# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in MySQL Table

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I created a database with one table in MySQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE iac_enrollment_system;

USE iac_enrollment_system;

CREATE TABLE course(
    course_code CHAR(7),
    course_desc VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    course_chair VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(course_code)
);
```

I am inserting records into the table with this Java code:

```
// Insert multiple records with user input into a table
// With separate methods

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

class InsertSQL3 {
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iac_enrollment_system";
static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "1234";

static int no_of_records;
static String[] saCourseCode = new String[no_of_records];
static String[] saCourseDesc = new String[no_of_records];
static String[] saCourseChair = new String[no_of_records];

static Connection conn = null;
static Statement stmt = null;

static void getInput() {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    // Get number of records
    System.out.print("How many records do you want to insert? ");
    no_of_records = scn.nextInt();
    scn.nextLine();
    
    // Get values
    for(int i = 0; i < no_of_records; i++) {
        System.out.print("\nEnter course code: ");
        saCourseCode[i] = scn.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter course description: ");
        saCourseDesc[i] = scn.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter course chair: ");
        saCourseChair[i] = scn.nextLine();
    }
}

static void executeQuery() {
    System.out.print("\nInserting records into table...");
    
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        for(int i = 0; i < no_of_records; i++) {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO course(course_code, course_desc, course_chair)" +
                "VALUES(?, ?, ?)";

            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, saCourseCode[i]);
            ps.setString(2, saCourseDesc[i]);
            ps.setString(3, saCourseChair[i]);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }

    } catch(SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
        
    System.out.println(" SUCCESS!\n");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        System.out.print("\nConnecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        System.out.println(" SUCCESS!\n");
        
        getInput();
        executeQuery();

    } catch(SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if(stmt != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch(SQLException se) {
        }
        try {
            if(conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch(SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Thank you for your patronage!");
  }
}
```

After I enter a course code, say, `BSCS-SE`, it returns this error:
[image: out_of_bounds]

Why is it out of bounds? Assistance is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numeric primitives have a default value of `0` in Java so the array `saCourseCode` is a zero-sized array which cant be assigned any values. Initialize the array after accepting `no_of_records`

```
no_of_records = scn.nextInt();
saCourseCode = new String[no_of_records];
```

This applys for arrays `saCourseDesc` and `saCourseChair` also

*Edit:*

Here is a template for initializing the arrays. Some code omitted but you should be able to figure out the rest:

```
class InsertSQL3 {
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/iac_enrollment_system";
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "***";

    private int noOfRecords;
    private String[] saCourseCode;
    private String[] saCourseDesc;
    private String[] saCourseChair;

    private Connection conn = null;
    private Statement stmt = null;

    private Scanner scn;

    public InsertSQL3() {
        scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    private void initConnection() {
       ...
    }

    private void getInput() {

        // Get number of records
        System.out.print("How many records do you want to insert? ");
        noOfRecords = Integer.parseInt(scn.nextLine());

        saCourseCode = new String[noOfRecords];
        saCourseDesc = new String[noOfRecords];
        saCourseChair = new String[noOfRecords];

        ...
    }

    private void executeQuery() {
         ...
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InsertSQL3 insertApp = new InsertSQL3();
        insertApp.initConnection();
        insertApp.getInput();
        insertApp.executeQuery();

        System.out.println("Thank you for your patronage!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the upper part of the code into this. Here is my [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/JzjGtPPP).

Comment: Wow, a lot of `static` variables there I would make those instance variables by creating an instance of your class

Comment: Hi, would you kindly show me a code snippet for this? Something just to serve as an example. Thank you.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you very much for your assistance. I have updated the code. Here is the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kxqPjHfj). It compiles and accepts the input, but it throws a `NonTransientConnectionException`. Here is a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/YKoahuA.png) of the error.

Comment: Don't close the database connection until after `executeQuery` has been called

Comment: I tried moving around the try-catch-finally to no avail. What must be done to the latest pastebin sir?

Comment: I will post a new question immediately. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Your arrays will always be zero-length:

```
static int no_of_records;
static String[] saCourseCode = new String[no_of_records];
static String[] saCourseDesc = new String[no_of_records];
static String[] saCourseChair = new String[no_of_records];
```

The arrays are created *immediately*, with the length from `no_of_records`, which is of course `0` as you haven't assigned anything to it and Java sets the default value of `int` to `0`.

I'd be pretty surprised if the compiler didn't warn you about that.

You want to create the arrays only *after* you know how many records there are.

Separately: I would strongly recommend **not** using `static` variables for this. This is the sort of thing you should have wrapped up in an instance.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input. Though I have followed Reimeus's solution, would you kindly show me the approach for "not using static variables"? When I do not use static, it is throwing me a "non-static context" error. A code snippet to serve as example would be much appreciated. I am interested to learn the elegant way of solving coding problems.

Answer (score 1):

A `static int` is initially `0` until it is assigned a value.
You need to create the arrays after you learn of their size, that is:

```
static void getInput() {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Get number of records
    System.out.print("How many records do you want to insert? ");
    no_of_records = scn.nextInt();
    scn.nextLine();

    // Now we know how many records we need to handle!
    String[] saCourseCode = new String[no_of_records];
    String[] saCourseDesc = new String[no_of_records];
    String[] saCourseChair = new String[no_of_records];

    // Get values
    for(int i = 0; i < no_of_records; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int no_of_records;
static String[] saCourseCode = new String[no_of_records];
```

is equivalent to

```
static int no_of_records = 0;
static String[] saCourseCode = new String[no_of_records];
```

So, all your arrays have a length of 0. `no_of_records` is only initialized after, in the `getInput()` method. Initialize the arrays after `no_of_records` has been initialized.

And please respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: The prefix "sa" was meant to mean "String array". In C, we were taught to prefix with "ca" for character arrays, so I just applied it. What is the accepted naming convention for Java String arrays?

Comment: The type of the object referred to by the variable must generally not be part of the variable name. In Java, there is an infinity of types: each class is a type. Name variables by what they are, not by their type: `courseCodes`, `courseDescriptions`, `courseChairs`. And variables are always camelCased. They never contain an underscore, except for static final fields (constants), which are spelled LIKE_THIS. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: Thank you, I will change my variables accordingly.